# in-place upgrade Windows Server Standard Edition 2003 to Windows Server Enterprise/Datacentre Edition 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

I recently asked a question about upgrading from 2003 to 2008, but i realised this is a lot harder to do, the only reason i want to upgrade is to have increase the RAM

> Windows 2003 Standard Edition R2 only supports 4GB
>   Windows 2003 Enterprise Edition R2 supports up to 32GB
>   Windows 2003 Datacentre Edition R2 supports up to 64GB

So basically i need to do an in-place upgrade to either Enterpirse or Datacentre without losing any data is this possible?
Also is one easier to upgrade to then the other?

Answer (score 2):

These are the supported upgrade paths for W2K3:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/evaluation/whyupgrade/supportedpaths.mspx

In general, when doing an upgrade, your programs and files will remain as they are.

Comment: So i can upgrade, thats what i thought

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an in-place upgrade from one edition to another, and even if you found a hack that claimed to allow it (they exist, at least for NT4 and Win2K) using it would put your server in an unsupported state (which is why I'm not providing any more info).

What you need to do is backup data and apps, reinstall Windows and anything else you need, then restore.

Comment: I have checked links and according to microsoft an upgrade can be done. I am just curious if anyone has ever done it and if programs and files etc stay